# Vagrant up fails with stdin, start, ssh, stderr & stdout errors

Tags: wordpress, ssh, cygwin, vagrant, windows-8.1

I cannot for the life of me...after reinstalling all things VVV/VBox(4.3.10) & running vagrant up --provision figure out why this beauty(VVV) wont run. I'm unable to access any of the wordpress sites such as http://local.wordpress.dev/.

Specs:
Windows 8.1
Cygwin

Final lines after running the cmd ->
    vagrant up --provision

```
==> default: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
==> default: Downloading phpMyAdmin 4.1.14...
==> default: Restart Nginx...
==> default:  * Restarting nginx nginx
==> default:    ...done.
==> default: Cleaning the virtual machine's /etc/hosts file...
==> default: Adding domains to the virtual machine's /etc/hosts file...
==> default:  * Added vvv.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default:  * Added local.wordpress.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default:  * Added local.wordpress-trunk.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default:  * Added src.wordpress-develop.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default:  * Added build.wordpress-develop.dev from /srv/www/vvv-hosts
==> default: -----------------------------
==> default: Provisioning complete in 1636 seconds
==> default: External network connection established, packages up to date.
==> default: For further setup instructions, visit http://vvv.dev
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: start: Job is already running: mysql
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chmod +x /tmp/vagrant-shell && /tmp/vagrant-shell

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
start: Job is already running: mysql
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 12):

Add the following line in your Vagrantfile

```
config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"
```

This starts bash as a non-login shell, but also tells it to source /etc/profile, which I hypothesised to be the only reason to use a login shell by default. Works for me with the stock precise64 Vagrant box.

Comment: Worked, thanks. I wasn't using MySQL so the accepted answer couldn't have been the solution, at least not for me.

Comment: Worked for me also with a PuPHPet configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Not anything you are doing. Apparently this is a known issue.

I fixed it by running `vagrant ssh`

and then

```
sudo service mysql restart || true
```

You can find a record of the issue [here](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/pull/383)

Comment: I never got to test this since I ended up moving to mac development(was on windows temp) & haven't developed on windows since. I'm setting up a similar dev env on my windows computer at work...albeit in my spare time. Initially accepted this answer because of the issue link posted...seemed solid. In light of new answers I think its best to remove the answer acceptance until I can test or someone can shed light on how to handle this.